What is the "class" of a manifold?
The beginning of this paper by Chern mentions the class of a manifold (bold added by me):

Let $R^n$ be a closed orientable differentiable manifold of an even dimension $n = 2p$ and class $r \geq 4$. In $R^n$ suppose a Riemannian metric be defined, with the fundamental tensor $g_{ij}$, whose components we suppose to be of class 3. Since we are to deal with multiple integrals, it seems convenient to follow Cartan's treatment of Riemannian Geometry, with the theory of exterior differential forms, instead of the ordinary tensor analysis, playing the dominant rôle. The differential forms which occur below are exterior differential forms.

What is the class of a manifold?

Smoothness, probably.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness
